# .ppm images saved incorrectly using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I am capturing images from a camera and save using opencv as follows.

```
cv::Mat leftImage(height, width, CV_8UC3);
//capturing image here
vector<int> compression_params;
compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PXM_BINARY);
compression_params.push_back(1);

 //writing as ppm image
 cv::imwrite("Image_1.ppm", leftImage, compression_params);
```

When saved as .png the image looks good[image: .png image]. But saving as .ppm[image: .ppm Image] is not giving the expected result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23802333/5008845). Otherwise the format is so simple that's maybe easier to write your own save/load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!!!

A conversion from BRGA to BGR did the trick.

```
cv::Mat leftImage;
cvtColor(leftImage, leftImage, COLOR_BGRA2BGR);
```

Comment: That's odd - your code shows a 3-channel `CV_8UC3` which wouldn't have an alpha channel (`BGRA`), just `BGR`.